# Where to find Geology data for Europe - GIS

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe, database

I'm looking for Geological/Lithological data for Europe in any scale (obviously more detail = better). Is there something similar to Corine Land Cover, but for geology?

CLC is great, because it standardize data for whole Europe, so there is one legend for whole Europe and we can compare different parts of Europe.

Data which I'd like to find could be either free or paid, but it should be vector data in GIS format (shapefile).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but do you mean something like Digital Elevation Maps (DEM) or something more detailed?

Comment: **What** data? How about adding a link to Corine Land Cover so that we don't have to go and search for it?

Comment: how deep do you want to go? just the surface (outcrops/ soil's bedrock)? aquifers? oil/gas reservoirs? basement?

Comment: Just the surface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst onegeology.org is great, and certainly there are a lot of European Geology WMS and some WFS services available.  In this situation I think that currently *<sup>(a)</sup>* you might be better off going to the [EGDI portal](http://www.europe-geology.eu/map-viewer/).  European Geological Data Infrastructure (EGDI) is a collective project of the European Geological Surveys, and EGDI is intended to showcase all geological data sets available as OGC services that have been created by these survey organizations, which includes services that they have made available on OneGeology

As part of the creation of the EGDI portal the survey organizations revisited their harmonized geology services (some of the old services are available on the the soon to be retired [OneGeology-Europe portal](http://onegeology-europe.brgm.fr/geoportal/viewer.jsp)), updating the attribution to use the latest [INSPIRE vocabularies](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist), and are working to create both [GeoSciML](http://www.geosciml.org) WFS and GeoSciML-Lite (portrayal) WMS, the latter of which will offer default styles based on the colours recommended by the [INSPIRE geology data specification](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/Themes/128/2892)

For EGDI the geological survey organizations have also created a collective harmonized geology simple feature WFS of some of the attribution from their fuller (complex feature) WFS.

The service endpoint for simple feature WFS is:

```
http://mapsrefdev.brgm.fr/wxs/1GE/EGDI_1M_INSPIRE_geolUnits?
```

So the WFS GetCapabilities is:

```
http://mapsrefdev.brgm.fr/wxs/1GE/EGDI_1M_INSPIRE_geolUnits?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&
```

You get both age and lithology data sets for surface geology at a variety of scales.  As it's a WFS you get the data to download as GML (shapefile is not available in this service), but you can use GIS software such as QGIS to convert the GML to a shapefile.  As it's a WFS you don't get any styling.  If you want to see styling for this data you can use the corresponding WMS, or if using QGIS you can apply the appropriate SLD as below:

- [CGMW colours, as used by ICS charts, and recommended by INSPIRE for age](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/sld/CGI-inspire-AgeTextURI-CGMW.sld)
- [INSPIRE recommended colours for lithology](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/sld/CGI-INSPIRE-lithologyTextURI-INSPIREcols.sld)

*<sup>(a)</sup>*: Eventually I expect that all harmonized geology services (WMS and WFS) will be available through the OneGeology Portal.

*DISCLAIMER.
I work for a European geological survey organization, and have been involved in OneGeology, OneGeology-Europe, and the EGDI projects.*

Answer (score 4):

Can I suggest OneGeology.org. It's a portal for open geological data from around the world.

It's mostly designed around their web map portal; http://portal.onegeology.org/OnegeologyGlobal/ which overlays Web Map Services (WMS) from many of the world's geological surveys. The complexity and number of layers can make it slow to load though.

What I suspect will be of much more use to you is the [map of participating countries](http://www.onegeology.org/participants/app/1gCountries.cfc?method=viewCountryMap) Clicking a country on this map will lead you to the individual country's geological survey organisation. from there you should be able to download a good deal of open geological data. Google Translate will be your friend in these cases too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Free data (https://energy.usgs.gov/OilGas/AssessmentsData/WorldPetroleumAssessment/WorldGeologicMaps.aspx)
   U.S. Department of the Interior | U.S. Geological Survey | DOI Inspector General
   Atention! Between Caribbean and Former Soviet Union maps you can find Europe maps (in shapefile formates) ones. The projection system I guess it's geographic WGS84.
2. With money (https://ccgm.org/en/maps/100-carte-internationale-geologique-de-l-europe-a-15-000-000.html)